# Azure Active Directory Authentication flow with Vue.JS (towards the backend api)

Tags: vue.js, authentication, azure-active-directory, passport.js, bearer-token

Heyhey people.

How do I pass a bearer token and other related information from the frontend (Vue.js) to our backend / /api/* endpoint so passport (running on node and express) can do its own authentication and authorization?

My client and product owner wants to use the Azure AD authentication and authorization flow real bad. Let's just assume for this question's sake that I cannot change anything about that, he's paying for the AzureAD tenant and I think there is a good reason behind all that.

This is the rough setup:

**- Frontend: Quasar/Vue.JS + vuex + vue-router + vue-msal (important)**

**- Backend: Node.JS/Express + passport (important)**

I've managed the following: Using "vue-msal", **on the frontend side / browser** I successfully authenticate a user with the msal-vue config and authentication flow set up and ready to go.
Now the question is, how do I send the authentication data, including the bearer token I acquired, to the backend and let passport authenticate the bearer?

Summary: **I already let users authenticate on the frontend/browser via vue-msal. The bearer retrieval works just fine. But you guys have any idea or hint on how I can make the backend, to be precise "passport" (in express running on node) authenticate the bearer token now, serialize the user and so on and so forth?**

Right now, passport knows nothing of the authentication flow on the frontend but it relies on the data from the authentication flow.

Historic side note: Our website worked with SAML authentication before. SAML, after user interaction and authentication on the browser, sent a POST request to /api/callback, which then let the backend do all the authentication logic. What I have currently is very different to that, and in order to make it work like it does now I had to rework the entire Vue.JS SPA lifecycle but like I said, this part works just fine now, it's all about letting the backend know and make the user authenticate, and in future, also protect all the /api/* routes with a bearer strategy.

Kindest regards and code on people.
Christian K.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this official MS sample, that shows how to authenticate users with MSAL and call a protected API:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api

The frontend is built with React but the backend seems to be exactly what you are looking for: Node.js/Express API using passport to validate the accessToken.

The flow is essentially the following:

- You authenticate a user on the SPA and acquire an accessToken for your Node.js API
- From the frontend, you call your API passing the accessToken as an authorization header
- When the request hits the API, passport will validate the accessToken: if valid, allows the request to proceed; if not, sends a 401 back.
- If the accessToken is valid, you can then access its claims

The sample also explains how to set up everything on the AAD portal.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sadly seeing limited results and it's mostly about the tenant configuration, but even if everything seems right, passport simply cannot let me pass, not unlike a certain Wizard and a Balrog.
Do you have any hints or suggestions beyond what you presented? Especially the passport.authenticate() directive in some kind of express middleware and even more so: 
How to correctly "build" a post with header body set right so passport shall let thou pass?

Comment: any luck with this @cirrus I am wanting to do something similar only with my react app.

Comment: @cirrus i think it wont work, because passport.authenticate will redirect the user back to the authentication server login page !